# Extended Linear Diophantine Equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While solving some linear equation I Stopped on the following:
How to rearrange coefficients and constants to find integer solutions for:
$2xy+3x+3y=106$. If we take $x$ as a common factor from the first two terms then we get:
$x(2y+3)+3y=106$. Any suggestion how to go farther..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4xy+6x+6y= 212$$
$$4xy+6x+6y +9= 221$$
$$ (2x+3)(2y+3) = 221 = 17 \cdot 13$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.